# How to add animation the featured image?

Tags: css, post-thumbnails

By default I choose featured image from media library. When I hover over each, It shows a black overlay with a plus sign. I have a cool css animation and want to add it to each post featured image. Below is the css animation code that I got from codepen. Anyone know how to do that? I just what to do it. Whether by adding custom css or using hooks or filter or from style.css. the simplest is better.

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <style>

        @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300);
html {
  height: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 32rem) {
  html {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

body {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333), to(#111));
  background: linear-gradient(#333, #111);
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.badge {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 20rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x1000) no-repeat 100% 50%;
  background-size: 120%;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.badge:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0.5rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}
.badge:hover .text {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px) rotate(-315deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px) rotate(-315deg);
  background: rgba(102, 51, 153, 0.5);
  width: 25rem;
  letter-spacing: 1rem;
  line-height: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin-top: -10rem;
  margin-left: -12.5rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1), letter-spacing 1.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1), letter-spacing 1.5s ease-out;
}
.badge .text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  line-height: 10rem;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5rem;
  margin-left: -5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(-10rem) rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(-10rem) rotate(180deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
}




    </style>



    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='badge'>
  <div class='text'>’Hallo!</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: There are various ways to add custom CSS. Check your theme first and see if it has a "custom CSS" area, often found in the Customizer. If not, there are plugins you can use to add your own CSS. Or, you can build a child theme or a plugin to enqueue your own CSS file.

Comment: I am working on a wordpress site which has wpbakery page builder installed.

Comment: in the animation I want to add, there are is a div that I should add to the html and some css to add to the custom css. even if I find how to add custom css to the featured image. I am still confused where to find the featured image html code to add that div. I am working on a theme named highend. from theme editor I can acess to style.css or any other php files. The only problem I have is where to find featured image html codes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your theme might already have an animation feature, you can just add the class.
2. You can add a plugin like so..https://wordpress.org/plugins/animate-it/ and add the class to the featured image property for it to work.
3. If you use a builder (like Elementor) you can easily create your layouts and add animations to each element.

Comment: Actually posts and pages are working by the help of wpbakery page builder plugin. that makes things complex.